# give styles to options text in select box using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had a options in select box. and i need to style particular text give text justify to options. I am using php,bootstrap and jquery.

Here is my code:

```
 <option style="margin:5px 5px;"value="<?php echo $totvalue['ID']; ?>" data-position="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php                 
                    echo $totvalue['Abbreviation'].' - '.$quotation.' - '.$totvalue['Name'].' - '.$totvalue['Category']; ?></option>
```

which is

```
<option style="margin:5px 5px;" value=1002>TAKAJ - A - SAMSUUNG - 4G</option>
<option style="margin:5px 5px;" value=1003>YEG - L - SONY - 3G</option>
```

I need `- A -` and `- L -` in options to be in `<span class="label label-success">`. How to achieve this using jquery..

Comment: I don't think you can style options: https://jsfiddle.net/bu9pmL21/ find some plugin like select2

Comment: `option` elements are plaintext only. You will need to use a custom select plugin.

Comment: yes I know but its needed. any other solutions

Comment: @BenM can you name the plugin

Comment: http://selectric.js.org/

Comment: @BenM I can't able to find the options styling in selectric

Answer (score 0):

Options in select input are generated by browser. You can't add style there. 
[options in bootstrap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUERP.png)

But you can create your own select in jQuery like here:

```
// Iterate over each select element
$('select').each(function () {

    // Cache the number of options
    var $this = $(this),
        numberOfOptions = $(this).children('option').length;

    // Hides the select element
    $this.addClass('s-hidden');

    // Wrap the select element in a div
    $this.wrap('<div class="select"></div>');

    // Insert a styled div to sit over the top of the hidden select element
    $this.after('<div class="styledSelect"></div>');

    // Cache the styled div
    var $styledSelect = $this.next('div.styledSelect');

    // Show the first select option in the styled div
    $styledSelect.text($this.children('option').eq(0).text());

    // Insert an unordered list after the styled div and also cache the list
    var $list = $('<ul />', {
        'class': 'options'
    }).insertAfter($styledSelect);

    // Insert a list item into the unordered list for each select option
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
        $('<li />', {
            text: $this.children('option').eq(i).text(),
            rel: $this.children('option').eq(i).val()
        }).appendTo($list);
    }

    // Cache the list items
    var $listItems = $list.children('li');

    // Show the unordered list when the styled div is clicked (also hides it if the div is clicked again)
    $styledSelect.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('div.styledSelect.active').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active').next('ul.options').hide();
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('active').next('ul.options').toggle();
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when a list item is clicked and updates the styled div to show the selected list item
    // Updates the select element to have the value of the equivalent option
    $listItems.click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $styledSelect.text($(this).text()).removeClass('active');
        $this.val($(this).attr('rel'));
        $list.hide();
        /* alert($this.val()); Uncomment this for demonstration! */
    });

    // Hides the unordered list when clicking outside of it
    $(document).click(function () {
        $styledSelect.removeClass('active');
        $list.hide();
    });

});
```

[See on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BB3JK/2270/)

Comment: I am using the multiselect plugin. And I have tried the above method yet not helps